# awk for loop how to see if one line exists in another file and compare dates lines of both files

Tags: bash, awk

This is `file-old.txt`:

```
nextduedate: '2023-09-06'
dedicatedip: 1.1.1.1
nextduedate: '2023-09-01'
dedicatedip: 2.2.2.2
nextduedate: '2023-09-08'
dedicatedip: 3.3.3.3
```

This is `file-new.txt`:

```
nextduedate: '2023-09-06'
dedicatedip: 1.1.1.1
nextduedate: '2023-10-01'
dedicatedip: 2.2.2.2
nextduedate: '2023-10-08'
dedicatedip: 3.3.3.3
```

This is `servers.txt` (maybe is necessary):

```
[
    {
        "server": {
            "server_ip": "3.3.3.3",
            "server_ipv6_net": "::1", # fake
            "server_number": 12345678974,
            "server_name": "some.host.name.com",
            "product": "Server Auction",
            "dc": "FSN1-DC11",
            "traffic": "unlimited",
            "status": "ready",
            "cancelled": false,
            "paid_until": "2023-10-08",
            "ip": [
                "3.3.3.3"
            ],
            "subnet": [
                {
                    "ip": "::1", # fake
                    "mask": "64" # fake
                }
            ],
            "linked_storagebox": null
        }
    },
# other server's details
]
```

I'm trying to do this:

> iterate over both files, check the dedicatedip in old file if it exists in new file, then compare the nextduedate of both, if nextduedate in new file is newer than the old file, then it should do something (an external command), else (which should be basically the same in both), it should do nothing.

Example and explanation:

> Check the IP 1.1.1.1 from old file and then find that line in new file, then compare both nextduedate. Since both are the same (in fact new is not greater than the old), then it should do nothing.
>
> Check the IP 2.2.2.2 from old file and then find that line in new file, then compare both nextduedate. Since the nextduedate of new is greater than the old file, it should be stored as a variable.
>
> Check the IP 3.3.3.3 from old file and then find that line in new file, then compare both nextduedate. Since the nextduedate of new is greater than the old file, it should be stored as a variable.
>
> Then if the nextduedate is greater than the old one, it should check for the value of "server_number" in the `servers.txt` to call an API.

The final result should be something like this:

```
# the awk code
# the api call, in the following line for example, server_number=12345678974
curl -u user:password https://url.com/$server_number
```

I know the `for` loop in `awk`, but my issue is that `1.1.1.1` is one time compared to `1.1.1.1`, then it is compared to `2.2.2.2` and then `3.3.3.3`, and then the `2.2.2.2` iterates all.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've attempted and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: what's the expected max number of entries you need to test/compare? what are you doing with the `curl` output? while it's possible to call `curl` from within `awk`, this may be overkill if you need to perform other processing; thinking it might be of benefit to have `awk` do the compares and spit out a list of ips (and dates?) and then have a `bash` script process the list of ips (eg, make `curl` call, process `curl` result) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is simple if that is all the files contain. For example, you can process them as records if you have an awk that supports multicharacter `RS` (such as `mawk` or `gawk`):

```
gawk -v RS=nextduedate: '
    FNR==1 { next }
    NR==FNR {
        date = $1
        gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",date)
        if (length(date)!=8)
            printf "bogus date: %s (%s)\n", $3,$1
        else if ($3 in n)
            printf "duplicate old: %s (%s)\n", $3,$1
        else
            n[$3] = $1
        next
    }
    {
        if (!$3 in n)
            printf "no old: %s\n", $3
        else if ($3 in seen)
            printf "duplicate new: %s (%s)\n", $3,$1
        else if ($1>n[$3])
            printf "process: %s (%s > %s)\n", $3,$1,n[$3]
        else
            printf "skip %s (%s <= %s)\n", $3,$1,n[$3]
        seen[$3]
    }
' file-old.txt file-new.txt
```

```
skip 1.1.1.1 ('2023-09-06' <= '2023-09-06')
process: 2.2.2.2 ('2023-10-01' > '2023-09-01')
process: 3.3.3.3 ('2023-10-08' > '2023-09-08')
```

---

If your server file is actually valid JSON (ie. doesn't contain those `# fake` comments, you can query it easily with `jq`. For example:

```
jq --arg ip 3.3.3.3 '
    .[] | .server | select(.server_ip==$ip) |
    .server_number // empty
' servers.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, at the moment I'm exhausted to check the answer and adapt it with my real data. But regarding `jq`, why did you use `ip 3.3.3.3`? Suppose We don't know the last one. I really don't know the last IP because that file is generated dynamically.

Comment: replace it with an appropriate variable when writing the loop

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's a specific requirement, there are "better" languages to simplify this type of task.

e.g.
python, ruby, perl or [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) as has already been suggested.

```bash
old=old.txt
new=new.txt

regex="nextduedate: '(?<date>[^']+)'\ndedicatedip: (?<server_ip>.+)"

jq --arg regex "$regex" --rawfile old "$old" --rawfile new "$new" '

def parse_ips(name):
  capture($regex; "g") 
  | {(name): (.date | strptime("%Y-%m-%d") | mktime), server_ip};

[
  (.[].server | {server_ip, server_number}), 
  ($old | parse_ips("old")), 
  ($new | parse_ips("new"))
] 
| group_by(.server_ip)[]
| add
| select(.old < .new and .server_number != null)
| .server_number

' servers.txt
```

```
12345678974
```

Here we create JSON for old and new using [`.capture()`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#capture)

```json
{
  "old": 1693958400,
  "server_ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
```

```json
{
  "new": 1693958400,
  "server_ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
```

Extract server ip and number

```json
{
  "server_ip": "3.3.3.3",
  "server_number": 12345678974
}
```

Combine the records with [`.group_by()`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#group_by) which we then filter.